# What's wrong with this send-one-way-request in Azure Api management

Tags: azure-api-management

We are experiencing some trouble getting our policy to work.

We want to log to an external party (Loggly) in case of errors above or equal to 400.  We think this is handled in the outbound section and can be achieved with a send-one-way-request. Also we tried to log via the on-error section of the policy.

Code:

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
    </inbound>
    <backend>
    </backend>
    <outbound>
            <choose>
                <when condition="@(context.Response.StatusCode >= 400)">
                    <send-one-way-request mode="new">
                        <set-url>http://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/<uid>/tag/Api_Azure</set-url>
                        <set-method>POST</set-method>
                        <set-body>@{
                            return new JObject(
                                    new JProperty("username","APIM Alert"),
                                    new JProperty("icon_emoji", ":ghost:"),
                                    new JProperty("text", String.Format("{0} {1}\nHost: {2}\n{3} {4}\n User: {5}",
                                                            context.Request.Method,
                                                            context.Request.Url.Path + context.Request.Url.QueryString,
                                                            context.Request.Url.Host,
                                                            context.Response.StatusCode,
                                                            context.Response.StatusReason,
                                                            context.User.Email
                                                            ))
                                    ).ToString();
                        }</set-body>
                    </send-one-way-request>
                </when>
            </choose>
        </outbound>
        <on-error>
            <send-one-way-request mode="new">
                <set-url>http://logs-01.loggly.com/inputs/<uid>/tag/Api_Azure</set-url>
                <set-method>POST</set-method>
                <set-body>TEST outbound ERROR: @(context.LastError.Message)</set-body>
            </send-one-way-request>
        </on-error>
</policies>
```

The result of this policy is that a request was send via the send-one-way-request, but the URL used in this case was the original URL instead of the one in the set-url tag.

Does someone have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Ok. Our bad ... Logging is working now, but the result of API Management is a 500 Internal Server Error instead of the expected 400 Bad Request, returned by the backend api. Do we have to add something to the policy to handle the error correctly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens if you try executing same request with tracing enabled? https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/api-management-howto-api-inspector/

Comment: Hi Vitaliy,

With tracking enabled it is showing a parse error. 

Forgot to use a choose when construction for a deep link injection when a request is processed. So if there was an error, this injection was executed too. Now we check boot response status 200 and than process the injection. Otherwise no action is taken. 

All well now! Thanks!